Understanding Function Definitions that Return a Function Pointer
I am hoping to get some help with understanding why function definitions, with function pointer return types need to be written the following way.
int ( * functionFactory (int n) ) (int, int) { Function Body }

function definition taken from How do function pointers in C work?
This is what I imagine each part means.
returned function's | function  Returns  |                  | called function's | returned function's
return type         | a function pointer | name of function | arguments         | arguments 
  |                   |                          |                  |                   |
 _V_                 _V_     ____________________V________   _______V_                 _V______
|   |               |   |   |                             | |         |               |        |
 int               (  *             functionFactory           (int n)  )              (int, int) { Function Body }

But why is it not written more like a normal function with the return type all together at the start like this.
return type       name of function  arguments
      |                 |             |
 _____V_________   _____V_______   ___V_
|               | |             | |     |
int (*)(int, int) functionFactory (int n) { Function Body }


FWIW if you use a typedef for the function pointer, all of the confusion disappears.

It is ultimately because Dennis Ritchie made the dereference operator * a prefix operator rather than a postfix operator. All this could have been avoided, and also the -> operator.

Honest answer: because function pointer syntax in C is deranged.

@nneonneo Then C++ came along, saw it, and said "hold my beer".

Perhaps here you will find comfort and understanding...

You can use typeof extension (a feature in C23). typeof(int(int,int)) * function_factory(int)

See Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C.

This is an artifact of the C syntax principle “declaration mirrors use”.
Given a declaration int ( * functionFactory (int n) ) (int, int), one way you could use it would be
int result = (*functionFactory(42))(123, 456);

in order to call the factory with the argument 42, then immediately invoking the resulting pointer with 123, 456.
Now, it’s generally bad practice to actually use such a declaration in real life as it would be widely considered unreadable. Instead, the usual advice is to use a typedef:
typedef int (*fptr_t)(int, int);
fptr_t functionFactory(int n) { … }


I would suggest useing function types.
typedef int myfunction(int,int);

myfunction *functionFactory(int n)
{
    /* the code */
}


This record
int ( * functionFactory (int n) ) (int, int);

can be represented like
int declarator (int, int);

where the declarator is represented like
( * functionFactory (int n) )

That is it is a function that returns a pointer and has one parameter of the type int. And the returned pointer is a pointer to a function of the type int ( int, int ) as it is seen from the shown already record
int declarator (int, int);

.
And it was already mentioned in other answers the declaration could be simplified using typedef like for example
typedef int ( *Fp )( int, int );
Fp functionFactory( int );

or
typedef int Func( int, int );
Func * functionFactory( int );

